# Defining equal height for views according to screen?

Tags: android, android-xml

How to display all Images height equal and it should match parent on any device?
How do I design that?

The image is the example.

[image]

desing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:src="@drawable/img1" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:src="@drawable/img2" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/img3"
    android:src="@drawable/img3" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Here I set a height of 170dp and this only fits for this screen, but in bigger screens the images will not fit.
I want to make it fit on any screen.

Comment: Share your current xml

Comment: make all image height same .....

Comment: give the imageview property android:scaleType="fitXY"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/image1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/image2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/image3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank You.. Exactly got what I mean!!

Answer (score 0):

Set layout_weight="1" to your three ImageViews. Set layout_width to match_parent and your layout_height to 0dp.

Comment: Weights only work in **LinearLayouts**. Refer to @TodorKostov answer.